# Position vtkChartLegend in Python

Tags: python, vtk

### Question

I am writing a script to build some line charts in VTK, but I am having difficulty repositioning a vtkChartLegend object.

The python script below will create the plot shown. I would like to reposition the legend to the upper left-hand side of the chart so as to not interfere with the line plot. However, I am not able to make the legend move. I would appreciate any help to get the legend to re-position?

I am running OSX (Yosemite) with Python 2.7.6 and VTK 6.3.

### VTK Output

[image]

### Python Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import vtk

# Num. points
n = 10

# Create some data
x = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
y = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
x.SetNumberOfTuples(n)
x.SetName('x')
y.SetNumberOfTuples(n)
y.SetName('y')
for i in range(10):
  x.SetValue(i, float(i))
  y.SetValue(i, float(2*i))

# Create the table and line
table = vtk.vtkTable()
table.AddColumn(x)
table.AddColumn(y)

line = vtk.vtkPlotLine()
line.SetInputData(table, 0, 1)

# Create chart
chart = vtk.vtkChartXY()
chart.AddPlot(line)

# Create view
view = vtk.vtkContextActor()
view.GetScene().AddItem(chart)

# Renderer
renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
renderer.SetBackground(1,1,1)
renderer.AddViewProp(view)

# Legend
chart.SetShowLegend(True)
legend = chart.GetLegend()
legend.SetPoint(0, 20) # This doesn't seem to do anything

# Window
window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.AddRenderer(renderer)

# Interactor
interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
interactor.SetRenderWindow(window)

# Render
window.Render()
renderer.Render()
interactor.Start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received a response from the vtkusers mailing list that solved my issue.

```
legend.SetHorizontalAlignment(vtk.vtkChartLegend.CUSTOM)
legend.SetVerticalAlignment(vtk.vtkChartLegend.CUSTOM)
legend.SetPoint(200, 200) # position in window coordinates
```